# Are JavaScript error messages consistent across browsers and locale settings?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, cross-browser, locale

Are JavaScript error messages the exact same across all browsers and will they always be reported in English (regardless of the client's locale settings)?

I have done minimal testing on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and IE on desktop and mobile devices and the answer to my question appears to be "Yes". However, I would like to know if there is an official answer to my question that we can trust.

Comment: In general *yes*, when it comes to platform oriented development, then you may extend it with something like https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n in each particular case.

Comment: They are not. If you've been testing, you should've noticed [differences](https://jsfiddle.net/nq1emchh/) between message texts depending on the used browser. Also, at least IE follows the language used in the machine.

Comment: No, for example `(a=()=>a())()` gives `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` in Chrome and `InternalError: too much recursion` in Firefox. There are no standards for error messages.